# Get the column position

Tags: r

Using the iris dataframe, I want the position of all the columns with *"Length"* in the column name.

I can find them manually using the below code but I want a method that will allow me to just search for the word "Length" without having to specify the exact column name.

```
iris_df <- iris

which(colnames(iris_df) == "Sepal.Length") # returns 1
which(colnames(iris_df) == "Petal.Length") # returns 3
```

Can anyone suggest any code to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `grep`:

```
grep("Length", colnames(iris_df))
[1] 1 3
```

Comment: Since we're dealing with a data frame, `names` instead of `colnames` should be sufficient.

Comment: True. However in situations like this, I find `colnames` a bit more intuitive to use than `names`.

Comment: I've often wondered in what situations either of them fail, since they both work equally well with frames and matrices (the two most-likely confuse-able objects, in my experience). The only "oops" I can think of would be `list(.)`, where `colnames` will not work. This can be good (i.e., quick-fail if the object is not frame-like), or this can be unnecessarily strict (e.g., `lapply(..)` on the frame returns a `list`). As always, "it depends", but it's an interesting thing to me. (I don't stay up thinking about it, though.)

Comment: I'd rather go with `library(stringr)`. In this case I would do: `str_which(names(iris), "Length")`

Comment: I see no benefit of using a library to do something that simple.